# Qualitative searches in neo4j graph algorithms

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have different entities and relationships in our neo4j graph. So there are different types of triangles that can potentially be in the graph,

CITATION -> CITATION -> CITATION

CITATION -> CITATION -> JOURNAL

to name a few. I was able to find all these in the algorithm to find triangles:

```
CALL algo.triangle.stream(null, null)
YIELD nodeA, nodeB, nodeC


RETURN labels(algo.asNode(nodeA)) AS nodeA, nodeA AS nodeAinfo, labels(algo.asNode(nodeB)) AS nodeB, algo.asNode(nodeB).CITATION AS nodeBinfo, labels(algo.asNode(nodeC)) AS nodeC, algo.asNode(nodeC).CITATION AS nodeCinfo ORDER BY labels(algo.asNode(nodeA))
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to specify the type of triangle in as a parameter of the function. I think I am only able to input a node type and a relationship type in the algorithm.

```
CALL algo.triangle.stream('citation', 'cited_by')
YIELD nodeA, nodeB, nodeC
```

What if there are a two or more node types and two or more relationships types - is there a way to specify these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 arguments to algo.triangle.stream can be Cypher queries returning the native IDs of the nodes of interest and the end-nodes of the relationships of interest, respectively. To indicate you are using this syntax, the config map must specify a `graph` property with the value of `'cypher'`.

For example, here is a snippet that shows how to get triangles involving `CITATION` and `JOURNAL` nodes, and `cited_by` and `referenced_by` relationships:

```
CALL algo.triangle.stream(
  'MATCH (p) WHERE ANY(lbl IN ["CITATION", "JOURNAL"] WHERE lbl IN LABELS(p)) RETURN id(p) as id',
  'MATCH (p1)-[r]->(p2) WHERE TYPE(r) IN ["cited_by", "referenced_by"] RETURN id(p1) as source,id(p2) as target',
  {graph:'cypher'})
YIELD nodeA, nodeB, nodeC
...
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful. I want to add "PERSON" as an entity and I am interested in triangles of "PERSON"s of the form PERSON1 -> CITATION1 -> ... -> PERSON2 -> CITATION2 -> ... -> PERSON3 -> CITATION3 -> ... -> PERSON1 . So, instead of triangles, I am looking for a set of disjoint paths connecting PERSON1, PERSON2, PERSON3 in a cycle. Is this possible by modifying the second query?